# How can I get a count from ManagementObject search?

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a bit of code to grab some information from WMI in C#, for the monitors hooked up to a computer.  The code is like this...

```
String queryString = "Select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryString)
foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
    ...
}
```

**How can I find out how many objects are being returned from this query, without counting during enumeration?**

Very new to this, so be gentle!  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to run the `Get()` function in order to get the number of objects:

```
  String queryString = "Select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor";
  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryString);
  MessageBox.Show("Found: " + searcher.Get().Count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are not asking that:

```
String queryString = "Select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryString);
Int32 i = 0;
foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
  i++;
}
// I have one computer so, i = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way here its for the method Count in Classes ManagementObjectColletion or in the ManagementObjectSearcher. If you gonna use the result, its better um do like this:

```
ManagementObjectCollection jobs = searchJob.Get();
```

and make the validation for the size like this:

```
if(jobs.Count > number) do
```